# Guake: autostart with several tabs and autorun different applications

Tags: linux, gnome

Is it possible to tell guake to start with e.g. 4 tabs, running cmus in tab 1, mc in tab 2,  htop in tab 3 and showing up the prompt in tab 4?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I use to launch 4 tabs when I'm doing rails development.

`guake --rename-tab="Rails Server" --execute-command="cd ~/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/sample_app/ && rails s" &
sleep 2 &&
guake --new-tab=2 --rename-tab="Rails Test" --execute-command="cd ~/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/sample_app/ && 'autotest'" &
sleep 2 &&
guake --new-tab=3 --rename-tab="Rails Console" --execute-command="cd ~/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/sample_app/ && rails console" &
sleep 2 &&
guake --new-tab=4 --rename-tab="Rails Terminal" --execute-command="cd ~/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/sample_app/ && clear" &`

Works like a charm :)

Comment: This form no longer works (on RHEL 7.2, for example).  It seems --rename-tab is now ignored unless --tab-index is specified at the same time.  Alternatively you can create a --new-tab (or --select-tab) in one command and *then* --rename-current-tab afterwards, but not together.

Answer (score 7):

It is quite possible, command line parameters support it.

```
#/bin/sh

# Just to be sure Guake is running.
# Guake handles multiple starting, won't create new instances
guake &

# Select first (0th) tab and rename it and execute something.
guake -s 0
sleep 1
guake -r "this-is-top"
sleep 1
guake -e top

sleep 1
# create a new tab in the ~ folder
guake -n ~
# rename the tab
guake -r "this-is-now-htop"
sleep 1
guake -e htop
sleep 1

guake -n ~
guake -n ~
guake -n ~
```

The 'sleep' is there for safe execution, without them strange things happened on my machine, feel free to experiment. The script ran well either guake was already running or not.